# Asking for user input from a list. Should the question order be randomized each time to reduce bias?

Tags: survey

I have a form that allows customers to cancel a service call they have scheduled, and would like to get reasonably accurate cancellation reasons.

Would I get more accurate results by leaving them in the current order which is more or less the frequency distribution of actual answers, or should the list be randomized each time it's shown to a user?

These are the current options:

---

- Found another company that can get here sooner
- Found another company that is less expensive
- Appliance started working again
- Fixed it myself
- Nobody will be home on the scheduled day/time
- Someone is sick
- Possible COVID exposure or quarantine
- Decided to replace instead of repair
- Other

Comment: Is there much incentive for respondees to give an accurate response? Particularly.if not, some will just tick the first box, or the last box, to get through filling the form quickly. On the other hand, an ordering that's somehow logical can ease rapid comprehension of the items.

Comment: "Is there much incentive for respondees to give an accurate response?" Not really.They have to check one of the boxes in order to cancel but I don't have a way to make them pick the real reason, or even an incentive to give them.Would this be a good reason to randomize the answers? If the answers are randomized and "the first one" is frequently picked, it seems like I could at least discard that. What about adding a first answer that rarely applies and can be verified, like "Severe Weather Warning"?

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but it relies rather strongly on the assumption that lazy/hurried people tick the first box. Randomisation of the order would remove any bias. It might introduce some noise though - when I read 'Appliance started working' I can already see 'Fixed it myself' below, & pick the latter if it's a better fit, whereas if they were mixed up I might well pick the first that seemed to be a so-so fit. Though your list of items isn't all that long, it could still be worth introducing a hierarchy: when respondees pick ''Appliance now working', they then ...

Comment: ... have the choice between 'Appliance started working' & 'Fixed it myself'. The less people are expected to read, the better.

Comment: I'd like to leave the questions about time and money, because let me know if I'm too expensive or if I'm booked out too far. I think at a minimum I'm going to start to randomize the question order and see how that goes.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting removing any, just perhaps organising them in a hierarchy. Top level might be something like "Found another company", "Appliance now working", "Can't make this appointment", & "Decided to replace", "Other". Either on paper or on a web page, that can reduce the total no. items the respondee has to go through. Of course you could still randomize the order of the top & 2nd-level items